# GAE Quotas: can i avoid denials?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have written an app on App Engine, and I end up using a certain resource completely. I know the quota and I can measure the pace at which I am using that resourse, so when I approach the limitation, I can just stop serving. I also keep within the per-minute limitations.

But still, I start geting quota denials after I've used about 90 percent of that resource. Is there a way I can avoid that? ("Going Billable" is one of the solutions considered, but are there any other options?)